# Whats the difference in way you installing full nodes

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, bitcoind, full-node

I'm newbie in blockchain world, so I'm curious what is the difference between installing full node by using libs such as bitcore-lib (using node.js) and installing it through the daemon (mentioned here https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#ubuntu-1604) (sudo apt-add-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin etc..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bitcoin Core daemon is better-reviewed and faster (because of C++). Bitcore lib is a Javascript library and not a node, the node version is Bitcore Node. You should ask yourself what you're going to do with a node. If you're a miner, the you shouldn't take risk and choose Core. If you want to use Javascript API, use Bitcore.